# Trying to loop several .csv with different date format

Tags: r

I am a new user and am in need of your help. I spent half the day trying to figure this out but ended up here.

#

I have hundreds of .csv files from dataloggers. All of these files have a column with "DATE" and I need to subset these files by "DATE". Some of these files have dates in different order.

Eg. :"08/27/2017" or "2017/08/27" or "2017/27/08.

I am trying to loop all these files to open them first, then convert the DATE column to date format using:

```
as.Date (filename$Date, format = "%Y/%m/%d")
```

However, because some files have DATE format arranged in different way, the above line of code has to be changed to something like below:

```
as.Date (filename$Date, format = "%d/%m/%y")
                        OR
as.Date (filename$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Is there a way to format a column as DATE irrespective of how they are arranged?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the date format within a particular file (or set of files) before you read it? If so, you can group the files by date format, read each set, format its date correctly, then combine the results into a single data frame.

Comment: you could try using `parsedate::parse_dates` to format date column of each file. Provided each csv does not contain an ambiguous set of dates this should work.  If dates within a file are all ambigous then there is no programmatic method to do this without further metadata about the files. By ambiguous I mean things like 06/07/12.

Comment: `lubridate::guess_formats` suggests formats based on given possibles.

Comment: Thanks a lot friends @dww. parsedate:: parse_date worked like a charm for me.  Saved tons of time subsetting files based on date column. I did not try lubridate::guess_formats. I am sure it will work as well. Thanks once again.